Rails UserMailer each vs bcc
I'm going to have to send a bunch of emails, and was wondering the less taxing way to separately send the same email to a bunch of emails.
I have to assume that
email_addresses = ApplicableUser.all.pluck(:email)
email_addresses.each do |address|
  UserMailer.send_email(address).deliver_later
end

def send_email(address)
  subject = "asdf"
  mail(to: email, subject: subject)
end

is slower and more taxing than
email_addresses = ApplicableUser.all.pluck(:email)
UserMailer.send_email(email_addresses).deliver_later

def send_email(addresses)
  subject = "asdf"
  mail(bcc: addresses, subject: subject)
end

but would like confirmation before switching them all over

You can pass multiple email addresses to to:. I assume you are taking this approach because you don't want recipients to see the other recipients of the email?

Does this answer your question? Send to multiple recipients in Rails with ActionMailer

Luke ty, yes - I was looping the UserMailer deliver_later in the controller through the email list to avoid recipients seeing all emails, but it seemed expensive after I realized I could put the whole email list through a bcc: like mail(bcc: email_list, etc) but I wanted a confirmation on this before I switched them all over (which I'm doing now regardless of confirmation)

It is slower because you did N requests to mail service when iterate through  email_addresses. Also you initiate mailer object in every iteration. It is also cost something
When use BCC — it is single request to mail service, single initialization of mailer object
But if you use some paid (or limited) mail service, probably it will count both cases with total email addresses
